# How can I add GCC as compiler for XCode9 on High Sierra?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, xcode9

I have installed High Sierra with XCode 9. I have read through all related Stackoverflow questions but none does seem to relate to my issue, let alone solve it.

I have installed gcc via homebrew. The output of ´gcc -v´ is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Now, in XCode 9 in ´Build Options´ in the field `Compiler for C/C++/Objective C´, the dropdown only shows ´Default Compiler (Apple LLVM 9.0)´...

I need G++ because I need OpenMP. Threads on StackOverflow have told me that LLVM supports OpenMP nowadays with some option in ´Build Options´ that accounts for OpenMP. However, I have not found such option.

Is there no way to enable G++ for XCode anymore?

Comment: Is this a "How can I get OpenMP working in Xcode" question more than a "Can I `gcc` in Xcode?" one?

Comment: @tadman my current question is how to get g++ working with XCode9 which also is of high interest to me even if OpenMP would work otherwise

Comment: I'm not sure Apple's concerned with `gcc`/`g++` interoperability at this point, so it might be a lost cause. There was a time when `clang` was still too rough around the edges and as a concession GCC was presented as an alternative, but I think that ship has sailed. Could you build a wrapper library with GCC and then import that as a dependency to your main Xcode project?

Comment: @tadman Maybe. But then, using OpenMP directly with LLVM9 would seem easier, if it was possible. Your comment is very worthwhile and maybe they do indeed no longer care about gcc/g++...

Comment: I might be wrong, but `clang` is evolving a lot faster, and in better ways than GCC at this point, plus Apple itself has very close ties to the `clang` project and LLVM in general both in terms of [personnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Lattner) and business reasons (Swift's compiler is [LLVM-based](https://swift.org/compiler-stdlib/#compiler-architecture)). GCC is just a historical artifact as far as they're concerned.

Comment: @tadman Knowing this, the question on whether OpenMP works with LLVM9 is indeed of higher importance to me. Since you seem to be very knowledgeable on this topic, do you have any insights on this question as well?

Comment: I haven't used OpenMP in conjunction with Xcode lately, Intel TBB for C++ and GCD in Swift have worked better for me, but I don't think OpenMP is unspported. There's [projects like this](http://openmp.llvm.org) worth checking out that explain LLVM + OpenMP in more detail. If you can confirm this as working, or prove it can't be done, might be worth adding a self-answer with the details to help out others.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm in the same boat. My professor is requiring us to use g++ over clang.